# How to match file name containing spaces

Tags: java, file, file-upload

We need to validate the file types. So certain file types should be accepted.

Actual code works fine as long as there is no spaces between file name. But when there is one, we get to the `"error ...!!!"` path and program says the file is invalid.

Example: `Home home.png` is marked as invalid but `HomeHome.png`  is marked as valid.

How can we match file name even if they contains withe spaces?

Below is my code

```
public boolean fileUpload(UploadedFile uploadFile) {

    boolean validFile = true;
    System.out.println("file date...!!!" + uploadFile.getFileName());
    System.out.println("file date...!!!" + uploadFile.getSize());

    String expression = "([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(jpg|xls|xlsx|doc|jpeg|png|pdf|ppt|pptx|docx|txt|xml|PNG|101701|AQR|ERR|CFR|RPA|AES|CAO|CIC|CAI|IMC|IMA|ITC|CDN|CIR|IMR|IME|ITR|CDR|CUN|CIN|CCN|CGI|IDL|IGR|IIL|IQL|NNL|SSR|STN))$)";

    if ((uploadFile.getSize() != 0)) {

        System.out.println(" file name" + uploadFile.getFileName());

        if ((!uploadFile.getFileName().matches(expression))) {
            System.out.println("error ...!!!" + uploadFile.getFileName());
            validFile = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you explicitly wrote you don't want to match spaces: `[^\\s]`

Comment: uploadFile.getFileName() and apply trim() to it

Comment: @Tejal did you read the question?

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do. Do you want to replace all spaces in your filename or do you match to match filename even if it contains spaces?

Comment: @jhamon   match to match filename even if it contains spaces

Answer (score 0):

Because you are skipping spaces in your expression. i.e  caret (`^` ) symbol

```
String expression = "([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(jpg|xls|xlsx|doc|jpeg|png|pdf|ppt|pptx|docx|txt|xml|PNG|101701|AQR|ERR|CFR|RPA|AES|CAO|CIC|CAI|IMC|IMA|ITC|CDN|CIR|IMR|IME|ITR|CDR|CUN|CIN|CCN|CGI|IDL|IGR|IIL|IQL|NNL|SSR|STN))$)";
```

instead use:

```
String expression = "([^\\.]+(\\.(?i)(jpg|xls|xlsx|doc|jpeg|png|pdf|ppt|pptx|docx|txt|xml|PNG|101701|AQR|ERR|CFR|RPA|AES|CAO|CIC|CAI|IMC|IMA|ITC|CDN|CIR|IMR|IME|ITR|CDR|CUN|CIN|CCN|CGI|IDL|IGR|IIL|IQL|NNL|SSR|STN))$)";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you okay with using regular expressions,try this

String fileName = uploadFile.getFileName().replaceAll("\s+","");

Comment: Use two Backslashes like this : ("\\s+","");

Answer (score 0):

(([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+.(?i)(jpg|xls|xlsx|doc|jpeg|png|pdf|ppt|pptx|docx|txt|xml|101701|AQR|ERR|CFR|RPA|AES|CAO|CIC|CAI|IMC|IMA|ITC|CDN|CIR|IMR|IME|ITR|CDR|CUN|CIN|CCN|CGI|IDL|IGR|IIL|IQL|NNL|SSR|STN)$)

This regix can deal with any space issues